# php date/time output mismatches the one shown on my system

Tags: php, date

I changed the timezone setting on my php.ini (xampp server) to `date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata`.

On my index.php I have this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:sa');
```

**Result**, I get is, 12-08-2015 11:42:49am, where as the actual date time at the time of running this script is 11-08-2015 11:12pm.

The date and time is like 12 hours apart from what actually it is.

Can you help.

Comment: Is the date/time and timezone set correctly on the server itself?

Comment: @JonathanM, I changed the php.ini timezone setting from Europe/Berlin to Asia/Kolkata on my xampp. I am testing my script locally.

Comment: What do you get when you add echo date_default_timezone_get(); before and after your code?

Comment: @bones, I did not do that but the phpinfo().php tells me, default timezone: Asia/Kolkata

Comment: @TinTin, setting the zone in php.ini does not set the timezone for the actual server. The server itself typically allows the admin to set time according to a timezone, which it then converts to GMT. GMT is what the actual server clock runs on. If the wrong time zone is given to the server, it will set GMT incorrectly.

Comment: @JonathanM, I read somewhere on Stack, before deciding to ask the question myself, that you need to change the timezone on the php.ini, restart and then try. The answer got accepted and I did the same. What should I do to rectify the situation.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @JonathanM, windows 7

Comment: In the control panel (or right side of taskbar) open up date and time settings and check the time, date and timezone for correctness.

Comment: @JonathanM, it worked. It was my windows settings, I need to accept your answer can you please use the "Your Answer" so that I +1 and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your system time, date and timezone in the windows control panel. Make sure it is accurate.

Comment: it works now. The timezone on windows OS was not set correctly hence the localserver was picking the wrong time and date. Thank you for the help.